# Zooming in and out of Scene in Cocos 2D-X 3.2

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm pretty new to Cocos 2D-X but have some decent background in C++. I have a sprite `_rocket` (tied to a Box2D body) that occasionally moves outside the visible view of my screen. I'd like for the view to automatically zoom out as the sprite approaches the edge of the screen, so that the sprite is always in the view. When the sprite returns to the original view frame, the view should scale back to its original size.

I was able to zoom out with the following code in the update function:

```
Size winSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
if ((_rocket->getPosition().x - _rocket->getContentSize().width/2 < 10.0) ||
    (_rocket->getPosition().x + _rocket->getContentSize().width/2 > winSize.width - 10.0) ||
    (_rocket->getPosition().y - _rocket->getContentSize().width/2 < 10.0) ||
    (_rocket->getPosition().y + _rocket->getContentSize().width/2 > winSize.height - 10.0))
{
    this->setScale(this->getScale()-0.005);
}
```

However, because `winSize` isn't updated, this essentially scales forever, until the sprite returns to the original view. I am not sure how to update `winSize` so that it can be used iteratively to find the screen's edge. There may also be a much easier way of approaching this.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why the winSize should change.
if you mean the _rock's contentsize not change

you should use

```
auto size = _rocket->getBoundingBox().size;
```

Answer (score 0):

They removed some useful camera functions in cocos2d-x 3.+

The workaround is to scale/move the layer containing the game instead of trying to move the camera.